# How can I make the storage of C++ lambda objects more efficient?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been thinking about storing C++ lambda's lately.  The standard advice you see on the Internet is to store the lambda in a std::function object.  However, none of this advice ever considers the storage implications.  It occurred to me that there must be some serious voodoo going on behind the scenes to make this work.  Consider the following class that stores an integer value:

```
class Simple {
public:
    Simple( int value ) { puts( "Constructing simple!" ); this->value = value; }
    Simple( const Simple& rhs ) { puts( "Copying simple!" ); this->value = rhs.value; }
    Simple( Simple&& rhs ) { puts( "Moving simple!" ); this->value = rhs.value; }
    ~Simple() { puts( "Destroying simple!" ); }
    int Get() const { return this->value; }

private:
    int value;
};
```

Now, consider this simple program:

```
int main()
{
    Simple test( 5 );

    std::function<int ()> f =
        [test] ()
        {
            return test.Get();
        };

    printf( "%d\n", f() );
}
```

This is the output I would hope to see from this program:

```
Constructing simple!
Copying simple!
Moving simple!
Destroying simple!
5
Destroying simple!
Destroying simple!
```

First, we create the value test.  We create a local copy on the stack for the temporary lambda object.  We then move the temporary lambda object into memory allocated by std::function.  We destroy the temporary lambda.  We print our output.  We destroy the std::function.  And finally, we destroy the test object.

Needless to say, this is *not* what I see.  When I compile this on Visual C++ 2010 (release or debug mode), I get this output:

```
Constructing simple!
Copying simple!
Copying simple!
Copying simple!
Copying simple!
Destroying simple!
Destroying simple!
Destroying simple!
5
Destroying simple!
Destroying simple!
```

Holy crap that's inefficient!  Not only did the compiler fail to use my move constructor, but it generated and destroyed two apparently superfluous copies of the lambda during the assignment.

So, here finally are the questions: (1) Is all this copying really necessary?  (2) Is there some way to coerce the compiler into generating better code?  Thanks for reading!

Comment: GCC gives the copy/move/destroy sequence you expected.

Comment: That's good to know.  I guess it means the answer to (1) is no.  Hopefully future MS implementations will be better.

Comment: What if you add move assignment operator?

Comment: I don't think it's really fair to dismiss C++11 features in VS2010 as inefficient; the respective dates should be a hint why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The standard advice you see on the Internet is to store the lambda in a std::function object. However, none of this advice ever considers the storage implications.

That's because it doesn't matter. You do not have access to the typename of the lambda. So while you can store it in its native type with `auto` initially, it's not leaving that scope with that type. You can't return it as that type. You can *only* stick it in something else. And the only "something else" C++11 provides is `std::function`.

So you have a choice: temporarily hold on to it with `auto`, locked within that scope. Or stick it in a `std::function` for long-term storage.

> Is all this copying really necessary?

Technically? No, it is not *necessary* for what `std::function` does.

> Is there some way to coerce the compiler into generating better code?

No. This isn't your compiler's fault; that's just how this particular implementation of `std::function` works. It *could* do less copying; it shouldn't have to copy more than twice (and depending on how the compiler generates the lambda, probably only once). But it does.

Comment: Hmmm...  I guess the only option then is to create a custom class to store the lambda (or wait for a better std::function implementation).  Thanks for the info!

Comment: @PeterRuderman: It's just some copying; let it go. It's not even something that happens when the `std::function` is copied. This is purely initialization-time. Are you really trying to store large structs in a lambda? Just use what's there, and if you profile and find an *actual* performance problem, fix it then.

Comment: Fair enough.  I may be engaging in premature optimization.  Nevertheless, I do think the copies are a valid concern.  I've been thinking about a design that would involve continuously creating large numbers of lambda objects.  It's quite likely that many of the lambdas will capture a std::string.  In this case, the copies are going to be really expensive.

Comment: couldnt you use the type of a lambda as a template parameter (using `decltype`) ?

Comment: @smerlin: Even if you could (and I'm pretty sure you can't declare a lambda inside a `decltype`. And even if you can, you can't capture anything except parameters. And even then, the type of every lambda is *unique*, so the lambda you `decltype` isn't the one you create internally) that would only allow you to return them. The actual type is still unknown, so the caller could only store them as `auto` or with a `std::function` or similar object. Also, you'd have to be writing a template function.

Comment: A lambda assigned to an `auto` variable is still strongly typed; you can use that variable in a `decltype`.

Comment: @MSalters: But you can't put the `decltype` in the return type of a function, since the lambda is defined *inside* of the function. You can't use `decltype` to transfer the type of the lambda outside of a function.

Comment: @Nicol: You can define the lambda at global scope. (5.1.2/3). You can even define it as a default argument in the declaration, and use the new trailing-return syntax to reference it.

Comment: @MSalters: And how exactly does this solve the problem that the person asking the question was trying to solve? You cannot store a lambda created in a function in any non-automatic (ie: not the stack) storage location without using `std::function` or something similar that performs type erasure. Not unless you are in fact writing a function template. And even then, the lambda member of a class would have to be declared at class scope and would therefore not be able to bind to much of anything.

Answer (score 9):

I noticed the same performance problem a while ago with MSVC10 and filed a bug report at microsoft connect :
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/649268/std-bind-and-std-function-generate-a-crazy-number-of-copy#details

The bug is closed as "fixed".
With MSVC11 developer preview your code now indeed print :

```
Constructing simple!
Copying simple!
Moving simple!
Destroying simple!
5
Destroying simple!
Destroying simple!
```

Comment: I think I should start using VC11. Too bad they didn't get variadic templates in...

Comment: @GMan: Any possibility to get VS to compile with GCC/Clang and still get all the features of VS? :/

Comment: @Xeo: Not that I know of, but that would be amazing.

Answer (score 6):

Your first problem is simply that MSVC's implementation of `std::function` is inefficient. [With g++ 4.5.1 I get](http://ideone.com/h4uNm):

```
Constructing simple!
Copying simple!
Moving simple!
Destroying simple!
5
Destroying simple!
Destroying simple!
```

That's still creating an extra copy though. The problem is that your lambda is capturing `test` by value, which is why you have all the copies. Try:

```
int main()
{
    Simple test( 5 );

    std::function<int ()> f =
        [&test] ()               // <-- Note added &
        {
            return test.Get();
        };

    printf( "%d\n", f() );
}
```

[Again with g++, I now get](http://ideone.com/6qO5o):

```
Constructing simple!
5
Destroying simple!
```

Note that if you capture by reference then you have to ensure that `test` remains alive for the duration of `f`'s lifetime, otherwise you'll be using a reference to a destroyed object, which provokes undefined behaviour. If `f` needs to outlive `test` then you have to use the pass by value version.

Comment: Capturing by reference is a very bad idea if you want to store the lambda.

Comment: As long as `test` is still alive (as it is in this case) then it's fine.

Comment: I do appreciate the difference, but I am interested in persisting the lambdas.  I'm contemplating a design where one part of the program would store large numbers of lambdas and another would execute them.  The example is just a test program I wrote to investigate the compiler behaviour.

Comment: "Your first problem is simply that MSVC's support for lambdas is terrible." It has nothing to do with their support of *lambdas*; it's the implementation of `std::function` that does all the copying.

Comment: Also the implementation of lambdas itself in MSVC doesn't seem to support moving value captured members of the lambda. http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=1108726

Answer (score 3):

Using C++14, you can avoid the copies altogether:

```
int main(){
    Simple test( 5 );
    std::function<int ()> f =[test = std::move(test)](){
        return test.Get();
    };
    printf( "%d\n", f() );
}
```

To produce the output:

```
Constructing simple!
Moving simple!
Moving simple!
Destroying simple!
5
Destroying simple!
Destroying simple!
```

Note the following line:

```
[test = std::move(test)]
```

Here, the first appearance of "test" is in a different scope than the second.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that std::function doesn't use move semantics and copies the lambda around while initializating. It's a bad implementation by MS.

Here is a little trick you can use to get around the problem.

```
template<typename T>
class move_lambda
{
    T func_;

public:
    move_lambda(T&& func) : func_(std::move(func)){}            
    move_lambda(const move_lambda& other) : func_(std::move(other.func_)){} // move on copy 
    auto operator()() -> decltype(static_cast<T>(0)()){return func_();}
};

template <typename T>
move_lambda<T> make_move_lambda(T&& func)
{
    return move_lambda<T>(std::move(func));
}
```

usage:

```
int main()
{
    Simple test( 5 );

    std::function<int ()> f(make_move_lambda(
        [test] ()
        {
            return test.Get();
        }));

    printf( "%d\n", f() );
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Looking at MS's std::function implementation, it seems like it simply doesn't have a move constructor.

Comment: It seems the auto generated lambda classes are non-movable, strange.