# Extra copy constructors when std::function is used

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, function-pointers

In my project, there are two components: producer and consumer. Producer is responsible for processing some information and giving the result to consumer. The result is passed with help of function object.

I am using a function for passing this information. You could see how it could look in the code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class Data {
    std::vector<int> vec;
public:
    Data()  { 
        cout << "Data()" << endl; 
    }

    Data(const Data& rr) : vec(rr.vec)  {
        cout << "Data(Data&)" << endl;
    }

    ~Data() {
        cout << "~Data()" << endl;
    }

    Data(Data&& rr) : vec(move(rr.vec)) {
        cout << "Data(Data&&)" << endl;
    }

    void get() {
    }
};

class Producer {
public:
    void process(function<void(Data)> f) {
        Data data; 
        f(move(data));
    }

    void process2(void(&pf)(Data))  {
        Data c; 
        pf(move(c));
    }

};

void Consume(Data a) {
    cout << "Consume(data)" << endl;
}

int main() {
    {
        cout << "use function() " << endl;
        Producer p;
        p.process([](Data a) {
            cout << "Consume(data)" << endl;
        });
    }

    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "use function pointer" << endl;
        Producer p;;
        p.process2(Consume);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it has the following output

```
    use function() 
    Data()
    Data(Data&&)
    Data(Data&)
    Data(Data&)
    Consume(data)
    ~Data()
    ~Data()
    ~Data()
    ~Data()

    use function pointer
    Data()
    Data(Data&&)
    Consume(data)
    ~Data()
    ~Data()
```

There are additional copy constructors when function object is used.

Did I do something wrong? Is it possible to get rid of these extra constructors?

Thank you in advance.

I am using VC10 SP1.

Comment: With g++ it just calls the move constructor 3 times.

Comment: `std::function` is big and expensive... hope you have good compiler optimizations, but there's a limit to how much can be optimized, given the vast flexibility that `std::function` offers you. In a crunch, prefer function pointers or `auto`/lambda over an explicit conversion to `std::function` when performance matters.

Comment: It will be fixed in MSVC11. See my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203211/how-can-i-make-the-storage-of-c-lambda-objects-more-efficient/8205037#8205037

Comment: is your production code using the same exact execution flow?

Comment: @refp, Similar, but not. I was trying to replace `const T&` with `T` in function arguments, but it is not so effective as I expected.

Comment: @Senik; Pass around a reference instead, no need for copy-constructors and such. A pattern can be designed to work with that approach instead of what you are currently using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options here.

- Don't use `std::function`, your non-capturing lambda is convertible to `void(*)(Data)`
- Don't use `std::function`, make your functions templates, the compiler can deduce the hidden type of the lambda.
- Don't copy objects, pass them around as pointers or references. Depending on what the full version of the program is doing, it may be more efficient to allocate on the heap and use `std::unique_ptr`.